# unresolved - org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator.generate

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, db2

I am using Spring boot version 1.5.4.RELEASE

I do have a entity defined as below

```
@Setter
@Getter
@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "EVT")
public class EventData {

  @GenericGenerator(
      name = "eventSequenceGenerator",
      strategy = "org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator",
      parameters = {@Parameter(name = "sequence_name", value = "SEQ1_EVT")})
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(generator = "eventSequenceGenerator")
  @Column(name = "EVT_ID")
  private BigInteger evtId;

}
```

I am using DB2 as database. My data source config from application.yml

```
  datasource:
    url: <my_url>
    ## Connection pool 
    tomcat:
      db-properties:
        clientProgramName: event
      initial-size: 0
      max-active: 150
      max-idle: 10
      min-idle: 0
      max-wait: 10000
      test-on-borrow: true
      test-on-return: false
      validation-query: SELECT 1 FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
      validation-query-timeout: 300
      remove-abandoned: true
      remove-abandoned-timeout: 360
      default-transaction-isolation: 1
      min-evictable-idle-time-millis: 30000
      time-between-eviction-runs-millis: 1200000
```

Once in a while I am getting below error.  In a day, roughly 5 times.

- Did I miss any configuration in application.yml?
- Do I need to increase my pool size?

How can I know which dialect to set from below in application.yml. My DB2 version is **DB2 v10.5.0.9**

1. DB2Dialect
2. DB2390Dialect
3. DB2400Dialect

```
Exception:
<unresolved>
Message:
<unresolved>
Stacktrace:
org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(<unresolved>:203)
org.hibernate.service.internal.SessionFactoryServiceRegistryImpl.getService(<unresolved>:68)
<unresolved>.<unresolved>(<unresolved>:47)
<unresolved>.<unresolved>(<unresolved>:242)
org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStructure$1.getNextValue(<unresolved>:96)
org.hibernate.id.enhanced.NoopOptimizer.generate(<unresolved>:40)
org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator.generate(<unresolved>:412)
org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:101)
org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.core.JpaPersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(JpaPersistEventListener.java:67)
org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:189)
org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:132)
org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:58)
org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:775)
org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:748)
org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:753)
org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1146)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:347)
com.sun.proxy.$Proxy.persist
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:298)
com.sun.proxy.$Proxy.persist
org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:508)
org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:542)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:504)
org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:489)
org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:461)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:56)
```

**Edit 1**

```
Exception:
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException
Message:
<unresolved>
```

AND

```
Exception:
org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException
Message:
<unresolved>
Stacktrace:
org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.getPropertyValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:633)
org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.getPropertyValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:624)
org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.getPropertyType(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:505)
org.springframework.boot.bind.RelaxedDataBinder.resolvePropertyName(RelaxedDataBinder.java:420)
org.springframework.boot.bind.RelaxedDataBinder.getActualPropertyName(RelaxedDataBinder.java:384)
org.springframework.boot.bind.RelaxedDataBinder.initializePath(RelaxedDataBinder.java:273)
org.springframework.boot.bind.RelaxedDataBinder.normalizePath(RelaxedDataBinder.java:259)
org.springframework.boot.bind.RelaxedDataBinder.modifyProperty(RelaxedDataBinder.java:240)
org.springframework.boot.bind.RelaxedDataBinder.modifyProperties(RelaxedDataBinder.java:155)
org.springframework.boot.bind.RelaxedDataBinder.doBind(RelaxedDataBinder.java:128)
org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.bind(DataBinder.java:740)
org.springframework.boot.bind.PropertiesConfigurationFactory.doBindPropertiesToTarget(<unresolved>:272)
org.springframework.boot.bind.PropertiesConfigurationFactory.bindPropertiesToTarget(<unresolved>:240)
org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(<unresolved>:329)
org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(<unresolved>:296)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1620)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(<unresolved>:230)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(<unresolved>:208)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolvePreparedArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:785)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:128)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1193)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1083)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(<unresolved>:230)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:372)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173)
```

Comment: Your write that your Db2 version is `v10.5.0.9`. This means the Db2-server runs on Linux/Unix/Windows.  So the dialect is NOT Db2400 ( for as/400 i-series) and it is NOT DB2390Dialect (that is for Z/os mainframes that run Db2 for Z/Os). So the dialect to use must be DB2Dialect.

Comment: Is that the __full__ exception text? I don't see any jdbc or Db2 content in the exception, which I would expect to see if the Db2 server returned an error.

Comment: Added some more logs.I am suspecting in first error log we have org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStructure$1.getNextValue. It's not able to get next sequence for some reason

Comment: IS the generator linked to a Db2 sequence-object? (sequence name __SEQ1_EVT  ) ?  If so, check the Db2-server diagnostics for the seconds preceding the timestamp of the exception.

Comment: Sure. Yes, it is Db2 sequence object

Comment: If the symptom is happening around 5 times each day, look in the Db2 diagnostics file (at the server, may be called db2diag.log or similar) at the same approximate timestamp as you see in the hibernate logs for the exception. Has Db2 logged any issue just prior to the exception timestamp? Look in `syscat.sequences` at the definition details of the sequence object, to verify its settings (cycle, cache, datatypeid , nextcachefirstvalue) etc.